# Custom validator in .ascx does not display the error message

Tags: c#, ascx, customvalidator

I am new to C#. I have this control on the page as follows:

```
     <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" HeaderText="There were errors on the page:" ShowSummary="true" ForeColor="Red"/>
        <asp:TextBox id="email" runat="server" />
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="emailValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email is invalid." ForeColor="Red" OnServerValidate="ValidateEmail" ControlToValidate="email" Display="Dynamic">*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

And in the cs code:

```
protected void ValidateEmail(object o, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
  ValidateEmailAttribute emailValidator = new ValidateEmailAttribute();
  if (!emailValidator.Validate(this.email.Text))
  {
    e.IsValid = false;
  }
  if (this.email.Text.Contains("#"))
  {
      e.IsValid = false;
  }
  return;
}
```

When the email is invalid it does not display the error message. All that is displayed on the page in red is :

```
    There were errors on the page:
```

But this is not clear enough for the user to understand where the error is. Why is "Email is invalid." not displayed ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger? Is the server side email validation definitely hit?

Comment: yes it is hitting the debuggers. e.IsValid = false; is called.

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to resolve this issue by adding this:

```
  this.emailValidator.ErrorMessage = "Email is invalid. '#' is not allowed in email.";
```